# No static method lambda$onGoogleApiClientReady$0 when updating to Gradle 3.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android, android-studio, lambda, rx-java

After migrating to the latest Android O with gradle 3.0.0 I ve got this error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method lambda$onGoogleApiClientReady$0(Lcom/patloew/rxlocation/SettingsCheckHandleSingleOnSubscribe;Lio/reactivex/SingleEmitter;Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationSettingsResult;)V in class Lcom/patloew/rxlocation/SettingsCheckHandleSingleOnSubscribe; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.patloew.rxlocation.SettingsCheckHandleSingleOnSubscribe' appears in /data/app/com.appx.app.debug-1/base.apk)
                                                          at com.patloew.rxlocation.SettingsCheckHandleSingleOnSubscribe$$Lambda$1.onResult(Unknown Source)
                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaf$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaf$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)a
```

my Gradle file :

```
  defaultConfig {
...
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true


    javaCompileOptions {
      annotationProcessorOptions {
        includeCompileClasspath false
      }
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainer of the library is [aware](https://github.com/patloew/RxLocation/issues/37#issuecomment-307329834) of this bug after deleting rtrolambda, and recommend to downgrade the version of Android Studio and use a stable one.

If you don't want to keep using Android Studio 3, use this fork :

```
 implementation 'com.github.joharei:RxLocation:master-SNAPSHOT'
```